# Child controller in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, architecture

Let's imagine a scenario where I have a Spring Boot app (in a controller/service/repository pattern) which contains controller for cars. Now I would like to create paths that look for example like this:

```
"/api/cars/bmw"
"/api/cars/mercedes"
"/api/cars/audi"
```

And so on. And for each of these car producers I would like to have multiple endpoints, some of them common for all car producers (not sure if it really matters but just for the sake of it lets say for example "/order" and "/cancelOrder"), but some of them different.

Now what would be the proper way to implement this scenario? Is there a way to make a CarController for the `/car/{producer}` path which would be a proxy for other controllers like AudiController handling `/car/audi` requests? Having 3 car producers in one controller and a service for each car producer is ok, but having 30 would make a lot of injected dependencies (30 services injected into the controller) if I would have only one CarController.

I believe node.js Express framework would allow us to do this in the car "controller" script (not sure if they are called controllers in express or what):

```
var app = express();
app.use('/audi', '{path to audi controller script}');
```

Is there a similar possibility in Spring? Or is this maybe a bad idea, an antypattern?

Another idea that is quite simple but seems not that elegant is to skip the CarController and implement a:

- AudiController with the `@RequestMapping("/api/cars/audi")`
- BmwController with the `@RequestMapping("/api/cars/bmw")`
- MercedesController with the `@RequestMapping("/api/cars/mercedes")`

etc.

So, what would be the best idea here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring has `@PathVariable` for this, which can be used in the following way:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/cars/")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("{producer}/cancelOrder")
    public String cancelOrder(@PathVariable String producer) {
        return "Cancel order for " + producer;
    }
}
```

We can call this endpoint like this: `http://localhost:8080/api/cars/Mercedes/cancelOrder`

There is no such thing as child controller in Spring. If you want to create a separate controller for every producer having some common functionality, you can use inheritance:

Parent controller class (please note that this does not have any `Controller` annotation):

```
@RequestMapping("/api/cars/")
public class BaseCarController {
    @GetMapping("/common")
    public String common() {
        return "Common stuff";
    }
}
```

Child controller classes:

```
@RestController
public class MercedesController extends BaseCarController{

    private MercedesService mercedesService;

    // Spring will autowire this by default, no need to add @Autowired
    public MercedesController(MercedesService mercedesService) {
        this.mercedesService = mercedesService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("Mercedes/cancelOrder")
    public String cancelOrder() {
        return "Cancel order for Mercedes.";
    }
}

@RestController
public class AudiController extends BaseCarController{
    private AudiService audiService;

    // Spring will autowire this by default, no need to add @Autowired
    public AudiController(AudiService audiService) {
        this.audiService = audiService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("Audi/cancelOrder")
    public String cancelOrder() {
        return "Cancel order for Audi.";
    }
}
```

We can call the produces specific endpoints like this:
`http://localhost:8080/api/cars/Mercedes/cancelOrder` or `http://localhost:8080/api/cars/Audi/cancelOrder`. Moreover we can call the common endpoint in the following way: `http://localhost:8080/api/cars/common`

Comment: Thank you for your response, although this does not seem to resolve the problem of too many dependencies. I still need to make something like a case switch statement that takes the producer string and depending on where its "audi", "bmw" or "mercedes" it will invoke the audiService, bmwService or mercedesService which means I would still need to have all the cars' services as dependencies in my controller. The whole point of the question was to eliminate the large amount of dependencies in the controller.

Comment: I guess I missed your point at first, I did some edit on my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: If you need different services to be resolved based on input, then I'd guess you need a `factory` pattern implemented somewhere. Ideally `Controller` can resolve the call towards a more generic `CarService` interface, that can rely on `CarFactory` to resolve the appropriate runtime instance and hence the functionality.